# Update with inner join?

Tags: sql-server

I have two databases:

```
DB1 and DB2
```

How to do something like:

```
update myServer.DB1.dbo.hotels.Name = myServer.DB2.dbo.hotels.Name

join myServer.DB2.dbo.hotels on myServer.DB2.dbo.hotels.Code=  myServer.DB1.dbo.hotels.Code
where myServer.DB2.dbo.hotels.CountryCoe !=  myServer.DB1.dbo.hotels.CountryCode
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
UPDATE  h1
SET     h1.name = h2.name
FROM    myServer.DB1.dbo.hotels h1
JOIN    myServer.DB2.dbo.hotels h2
ON      h2.Code = h1.Code
WHERE   h1.CountryCode <> h2.CountryCode
```

Comment: Picked this over SQLMenace' identicial version because ON clause is on it's own line -- necessary, when you have AND clauses within your ONs...

Answer (score 2):

example

```
update h1 
set h1.Name = h2.Name
from DB1.dbo.hotels.Name h1
join DB2.dbo.hotels  h2 on h1.Code= h2.Code
where h2.CountryCoe !=  h1.CountryCode
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for you.  You were missing the SET and FROM clauses.

```
UPDATE DB1
SET DB1.Name = DB2.Name 
FROM DB1.dbo.hotels DB1
INNER JOIN DB2.dbo.hotels DB2 
ON DB2.Code = DB1.Code 
WHERE DB2.CountryCoe !=  DB1.CountryCode
```