# update column based on 2 keys sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following database tables

- Master Table – Contains PK Id column  for a data range
- Reference Table – A staging table with the data range that has the associated code
- Target Table – Table for which the Id column is to be inserted or updated based on the master and reference table

---

```
    Reference Table
          Code      From        To
          Abc45     200        400
          Cde78     0          128
          Fcde1     600        898

    Master Table
          Id        From        To
           1        1          100
           2        200        400
           3        0          128
           4        600        898

    Target Table
         Name      id      City      Country      Code
         West               B          CC         Fcde1
         East               V          GG         Cde78 
         North              T          TT         Abc45
         South              Z          YY         Abc45
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: are the ranges in master table and reference table identical ?

Comment: Two other questions, 1) Are the values in column "Name" UNIQUE? 2) what are your expected values in your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE  t
SET     t.id = other.id
FROM    Traget t
JOIN    (SELECT r.code, m.id
      FROM Master m
      INNER JOIN Reference r ON m.From = r.From AND m.To = r.To
      ) other
ON      t.Code = other.Code
```

I used this question [Update with inner join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849534/update-with-inner-join) as reference.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 't'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near 'code'.

Comment: It seems that syntax doesn't work on sql-server, my bad. UPDATE FROM seems the matching thing, I'll look it up and alter my query then.

Comment: @Gallop okay, I rewrote the example to more closely match the referenced question that already got a 'working' hook.